# Open multiple Chrome tabs, but all suspended until I refresh them one-by-one (Preferably via BAT file)

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, browser

Is it possible to open let's say, 15 tabs, but all suspended until I pick the tab I want and activate it via refresh?

Also, is this possible via Batch file? I want to pre-load the tabs with the URLS of my choice, that why I would prefer to start via BAT.

I already know how to open multiple tabs in Batch file, but not suspended.

Thanks.

Found nothing yet. Maybe you guys know a trick or two.